# Way to trace magic methods that were invoked during code execution

Tags: python-3.x, trace, magic-methods

Is there a way to trace Python magic methods that were invoked during code execution?
For example, if I have this program:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

## Some wonder function or decorator that starts tracing

b = a()
b.x = 1
a.x = 2
```

And result would be all magic methods that was called for last 3 statements, including `__setattr__`, `__getattr__`, e.t.c.

The problem is I'm trying to figure what methods and with what arguments are getting called when, and on what classes/objects they are defined and documentation isn't very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You can carefully define a `__getattribute__` function to find out. The problem is Python will not call magic methods that don't exist... it's probably best to just read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)